Why weren’t Gad & Asher considered Leah’s 5th and 6th sons
This question has more than one question in it.
First of all in the game of having children between Rachel & Leah in Genesis 29:31-Genesis 30:22, Leah originally has 4 sons and in Rachel’s jealousy, Genesis 30:3 records:

Then she said, “Here is Bilhah, my servant. Sleep with her so that she
can bear children for me and I too can build a family through her.”

That servant had 2 sons which Rachel named Dan then Naphtali. 1- so, who’s the mom? Who raises the child and who does the child acknowledge is his mom? Also if Rachel wanted to build a family through Bilhah are those boys considered hers or are they forgotten when her own —Joseph is born.
Leah also gives her servant in this game as per Gen 30:17, 18 -

God listened to Leah, and she became pregnant and bore Jacob a fifth
son. Then Leah said, “God has rewarded me for giving my servant to my
husband.”

First of all it wouldn’t make sense for God to “reward” her for forcing her servant to have a child with her own husband. Second, her servant already had both Gad and Asher. Why wouldn’t Gad be the fifth and not Ishacar???
The same thing happened with Hagar in Gen 16:1, 2

Now Sarai, Abram’s wife, had borne him no children. But she had an
Egyptian slave named Hagar; so she said to Abram, “The Lord has kept
me from having children. Go, sleep with my slave; perhaps I can build
a family through her.”

The servants are forced to have sex with their masters (women) husbands with the claim of having a family through them but then when their own child comes they get pushed aside/kicked out. What is this? Explanation please

It sounds bizarre to us today, but this was common practice in those times.

The practice isn’t bizarre to me. There are MANY biblical practices not used today. In my question I asked who the child considered to be the mother and also whatever happened to them wanting to start a family through the slaves only to disregard their so called sons afterward. That’s not practice of forcing slaves to get pregnant by their own husbands. It now becomes a total different matter. That’s the actual question I asked here to begin with

Then this speaks to a more general question that while these "maids" started out as such, they ended up as fully fledged wives.

It’s more about the children than the maids as I’ve re-iterated. It’s ok if you can’t answer that. That’s why I posted the question so that someone can maybe answer it. Comments/personal opinions don’t answer who the children acknowledged as their mother or why their disregarded afterward

The OP is constructed in a way that makes a full answer unwieldly, so let me deal with one key issue.
וַתֹּ֣אמֶר לֵאָ֗ה נָתַ֤ן אֱלֹהִים֙ שְׂכָרִ֔י אֲשֶׁר־נָתַ֥תִּי שִׁפְחָתִ֖י לְאִישִׁ֑י וַתִּקְרָ֥א שְׁמ֖וֹ יִשָּׂשכָֽר׃

And Leah said, “God has given me my reward (Heb. sekhari, connected
with “Issachar”) for having given my maid to my husband.” So she named
him Issachar.

The OP states:

First of all it wouldn’t make sense for God to “reward” her [Leah] for
forcing her servant to have a child with her own husband.

It might not make sense to us today, but this is Leah's perception, not a declaration by the narrator.  Verse 9 indicates that Leah had stopped bearing children and that she gave Zilpah to Jacob at that time, just as Rachel had done with Bilhah when Rachel appeared to be barren. Leah perceived her unexpected son Issachar to be a reward from God for having put the clan's welfare (in terms of fertility) first by sharing her husband with Zilpah. This may not make sense to a modern reader, but it certainly might have to Leah.
Also, rather than being forced, Zilpah was given a high honor by her mistress, raising her from the rank of slave/servant to that of concubine/wife. Keep in mind that none of these women were free agents. Even Rachel and Leah - as other wealthy women - were the property of their fathers at first and then their husbands.
I will leave the other questions for others to answer if they are so inclined.

It has nothing to do with “now” or modern readers. This once again was a personal opinion completely ignoring the children. Once again, for non “modern” readers: who do the children view as the mother and why weren’t Gad and Asher Leah’s 5th & 6th sons. That’s it. Simple. It’s ok if you can’t answer the actual question but thanks in advance if you answer the actual question.

@Lyd.. I have to insist... Leah understood her unexpected pregnancy as a reward from God for putting the fertility of her clan above her personal claims on her husband. Modern people do not think like that, but she did. It's clear that modern readers do have a problem understanding this. Otherwise you would not have asked about it.

I actually never asked about her perception, I already knew that. If you would read the question correctly I said once again “ First of all it wouldn’t make sense for God to “reward” her for forcing her servant to have a child with her own husband. Second, her servant already had both Gad and Asher. Why wouldn’t Gad be the fifth and not Ishacar???” —- I stated how ridiculous the perception was and continued with the question— once again why weren’t GAD and ASHER considered her 5th and 6th sons. Once again if you are capable of answering that question I highly appreciate it. If not it’s ok!

Note the word "bore". The text you quote says she bore Jacob a fifth son.  Issachar was the 5th she actually bore.
Also, in the competition between the two sisters, they contrived their own game of one-upmanship, but it is likely that the next generation didn't perpetuate that.  Further, Jacob certainly saw the natural children of his favorite wife as more significant than the rest - he didn't prefer those of Rachel's servant, as he did Joseph and Benjamin.

I didn’t quote a verse that’s in the Bible. I added a verse in my question like I’m supposed to. That specific translation used the word “bore”, in a different one in Genesis 30:3-6 it says: Then Rachel said here is my slave girl Bilhah. Have sexual relations with her so she can give birth to a child for me. Then I can have my own family through her." 4 So Rachel gave Bilhah, her slave girl, to Jacob as a wife, and he had sexual relations with her. 5 She became pregnant and gave Jacob a son. 6 Rachel said, "God has judged me innocent. He has listened to my prayer and and has given me a

son," so she named him Dan.
In other translations it says “so that she may give birth on my behalf”…so it’s not a matter of words used in a translations, it’s a matter of Dan is supposedly Rachel’s  first born. Just like Gad should be Leah’s 5th— I could be wrong though
